# Recommended ways of dealing with a persistent database communication fault during a heavy database access method

Tags: c++, database, algorithm

I have a routine task runs a method that does some significant database access. It lasts around 1 minute (and can last up to 4 minutes) and runs in a separate thread every 5 minutes.

I already have the database connection monitored by another thread, which writes on a flag (**postgres_not_ok**) and that returns if the method is to be executed.

However, I want to avoid/interrupt its execution in case of a communication fault during the task execution. So what's the most recommended way of doing so?

Example:

```
// method executed in such task
void EnergyCalculator::dataProcessingTask()
{           
    if(postgres_not_ok)
        return;
    
    getSolarDataFromPostgre();  //gets a lot of stuff   
    getPowerDataFromPostgre();  //gets a lot of stuff  
    getEnergyDataFromPostgre(); //gets a lot of stuff  
    ...

    // But I want to exit this method at any point if the connection with the Database fails 

    calculatePowerAndSaveInPostgres();    //saves a lot of stuff  
    calculateEnergyAndSaveInPostgres();`  //saves a lot of stuff
    calculateExpensesAndSaveInPostgres(); //saves a lot of stuff
    ...
}
```

If the connection fails while this method is running, I want to exit this method as soon as possible to avoid having to treat a lot of Database exceptions within the functions of the method. Thoughts?

Comment: the question is unclear. Are you looking for `if (something_failed) return;` ?

Comment: Isn't it the purpose of that `postgres_not_ok` variable that you already have ? If that so, you could just redo the same test before calling any of those functions.

Comment: Any "connection pool" library will keep database connections alive as needed.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number No quite that. I'm actualy more concerned about the best way to proceed with a communication failure while in the middle of the Database access functions (Lets say, while getEnergyDataFromPostgre is executing).

Comment: @Fareanor I could, but I want to avoid having to check the flag at every function of the method (and the ones inside them) which would be slow and make code maintenance worse. It doesn't look like a "smart" way to do it? I'm thinking if a try/catch scheme could be the most recommended or something else that could stop it during execution. (Mutex with condition variable for example?)

Comment: @TheImpaler There is one! I'm thinking of a way to deal with a persistent communication fault (maybe that should have been added to the title). The database application may eventually be unreachable or completely down for minutes/hours, so I'm thinking on what to do when such fault happens *during* the heavy database access.

Comment: @lucasllfortes A try-catch mecanism would still require to have `throw`s inside all these functions (that would themselves be triggered on some way to check for the connection state) which would add even more boilerplate. As for using a mutex + a condition variable, I fail to see how it could be of any help here. It's more a way to synchronize threads (to block them, not to interrupt them).

Comment: For me, if such a check is really needed, each function could embed (for example at first instruction) its own check, so that it won't dirty the user code (they can then throw an exception that could be catched later on, one catch for all successive calls).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this and limit code replication as much as possible would be to delegate the responsibility to check for the connection status to the primitive functions that actually interact with the database (i.e. those which actually read/write data using the connection) and let them throw an exception if the connection has been lost.

Doing this way allows you to not have to care about it anymore. In your code, you can just have a single try-catch block.

A simplified example to illustrate it could look like this:

```
// Function that checks the connection
void check_conn()
{
    if(postgres_not_ok) throw my_custom_exception("my custom what() message");
}

// ...

// Primitive function for database reads
void EnergyCalculator::getData(/*parameters if any*/)
{
    // Check for the connection
    check_conn();

    // Get the data from the database
    // ...
}
// Primitive function for database writes
void EnergyCalculator::saveData(/*parameters if any*/)
{
    // Check for the connection
    check_conn();

    // Save the data into the database
    // ...
}

void EnergyCalculator::getSolarDataFromPostgres()
{
    getData(/*parameters if any*/);
    // ...
}
// ... And so on for all the other functions ...

void EnergyCalculator::dataProcessingTask()
{
    try
    {
        getSolarDataFromPostgres();
        // ...
    }
    catch(const my_custom_exception & ex) // Can use std::exception if my_custom_exception actually derives from it
    {
        // Handle the exception
        // ...
    }
}
```

All the functions should use the primitives `EnergyCalculator::getData()` and `EnergyCalculator::saveData()` to interact to the database.

This way, you only have to write the check twice (into the two primitive functions), and for the rest, a single try-catch block could handle it.

Comment: I appreciate the time! That fits well to my needs. It's the kind of idea I was expecting to be usual and reliable, just couldn't picture it at the time. Exceptions are a good way to just abort a method or functions within it.

Comment: I wonder (out of curiosity) if there is anything (like a class, library or other c++ implementation) that could do the same without the need of writing `throw`'s and abort the main method? Or would it have to be a task/thread killer of some sort? (Probably not very safe hehe)

Comment: @lucasllfortes Actually you only need to write `throw` only once (in the `check_conn()` function) and to call this function only twice (for each primitive). And then you can forget it. As for the catch, it's not mandatory to put it in the main, feel free to catch the exception at any stage that suit your needs. Now if you want something that kills threads/functions, I do not know anything that would be safe/portable. But it would probably not worth the effort, unless you really can't use exceptions handling (e.g. exceptions are deactivated for performances purposes, etc...)

Comment: But since you have a postgres database, if you use for example libpqxx, actually, the lib already throws exceptions if you try to perform an operation on a lost connection so maybe you doesn't need to check anything at all. All you need would be a try-catch clause.

Comment: Yes, yes! There's no need to write more throws in the Database functions (getData/saveData). I just know I execute some other processing before saving again into the Database and I know some other exceptions (not related to the database) can happen. As for the "thread killer", I was just curious if something of that sort happened to exist and the risks associated with it. 

And as for the libpqxx, thank you for the suggestion I shall look it up. Very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what database access library or API you're using, but some concepts are universal.

### Approach 1: Connect - do work - disconnect

It's generally going to be dangerous to have one long-term connection to your database. The TCP connection get closed behind your back, and you wouldn't know it until you tried to use it. So one approach is to:

```
# connect to the database
conn = Database.CreateConnection();
try
    # Perform the database operations on the connection we just opened
    getSolarDataFromPostgre(conn);  //gets a lot of stuff   
    getPowerDataFromPostgre(conn);  //gets a lot of stuff  
    getEnergyDataFromPostgre(conn); //gets a lot of stuff  

    calculatePowerAndSaveInPostgres(conn);    //saves a lot of stuff  
    calculateEnergyAndSaveInPostgres(conn);   //saves a lot of stuff
    calculateExpensesAndSaveInPostgres(conn); //saves a lot of stuff   
finally
    #gracefully shut down the database connection
    Database.CloseConnection(conn);
```

If the database connection fails during your activity, your database access code would throw an exception, which would cause the broken (i.e. poisoned) connection to be closed.

### Approach 2: Connect - and - check-every-so-often

Creating a connection and closing it is good in the web-server realm; where you open a connection to service the incoming request, and close the connection when you're done. But maybe you don't want to suffer the delay of repeatedly connecting. Most database access libraries support connection pooling to alleviate this issue, but maybe you still want one connection.

**Note**: Most database APIs (e.g. ODBC) don't react too well to access the objects from multiple threads. So the general rule is if you're having multiple threads, each should open its own connection. But we'll pretend we're only talking about one thread.

The other approach is to periodically check the database connection when you go to use it. So the above code would be changed to:

```
# connect to the database
conn = Database.GetConnection();

# Perform the database operations using that connection
getSolarDataFromPostgre(conn);  //gets a lot of stuff   
getPowerDataFromPostgre(conn);  //gets a lot of stuff  
getEnergyDataFromPostgre(conn); //gets a lot of stuff  

calculatePowerAndSaveInPostgres(conn);    //saves a lot of stuff  
calculateEnergyAndSaveInPostgres(conn);   //saves a lot of stuff
calculateExpensesAndSaveInPostgres(conn); //saves a lot of stuff
```

It's very similar, except that rather than opening (and closing) a new connection every time, we check if our *global* connection is still good. We'll only check it at most every 5 seconds:

```
Connection GetConnection()
{
   DateTime nowUtc = DateTime.NowUtc();
   if ((nowUtc - m_lastDatabaseCheckTimeUtc).ToSeconds() < 5)
      return m_connection;

   # Check if the connection is still working
   if (TestConnection(m_connection))
   {
      m_lastDatabaseCheckTime = nowUtc;
      return m_connection;
   }

   # The connection is broken. Close and reopen it
   m_connection.Close();
   m_connection.Open();

   m_lastDatabaseCheckTime = nowUtc;
   return m_connection;
}
```

**Note**: I did not try to write anything in C++. I just wrote in a mishmash of languages just to get the point across.

We use both methods where appropriate.